# Code coverage of client/server web application

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, sonarqube

I am writing a multi-module application. Some of the modules are just basic Java libraries which are then included in the WAR of a webapp.

I would like to run code coverage in the following scenario:

- I am running the webapp through an embedded Jetty that is started via Maven.
- I have tests which are executing HTTP requests against the webapp.
- I would like to get code covered in the webapp and also by the tests.

Is this possible and how can it be achieved with Cobertura, JaCoCo or Emma? From what I understand, the code coverage will only cover the client-side code in this scenario. Am I correct?

Comment: Out of interest: could you explain how you execute the tests? Does this work automatically or do you need to instrument the jetty and the caller manually?

Comment: Well, at the moment I have a Maven based project which launches a Jetty with one of the web modules. The code coverage executes in Jenkins using the Sonar plugin. The tests are JUnit 4.x. If possible, I think I need to use JaCoCo. Do I need to be using some Maven plugin for this, or will it get picked up by Sonar...?

Comment: The JaCoCo Maven Plugin in the project will start the agent and the Post-build Action in Jenkins will instrument Sonar. That's how it works here with the Unit Tests.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you would manage to attach the JaCoCo-agent to the jvm that runs the jetty, it should be able to measure which code has been called over the time you run the integration tests against your webapp. So you should get a statistic that shows you the code coverage.

There is a JaCoCo Maven Plugin - though I'm not sure if this will help with you scenario. Just used it during unit tests.

Edit: found a blog-post that seems to point in the right direction here
[Measure Code Coverage by Integration Tests with Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/measure-code-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar/)

Answer (score 2):

*Here's how I achieved it*

Assuming you already have a minimal pom.xml config:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</
  <version>0.7.4.201502262128</vers
</plugin>
```

1. [Download JaCoCo's agent](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jacoco%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jacoco%22) and copy `jacocoagent.jar` to a suitable location (e.g. `$HOME/tools/jacocoagent0.7.4.jar`)
2. Attach JaCoCo's agent to Maven's JVM via:

   ```
   export MAVEN_OPTS="$MAVEN_OPTS \
   -javaagent:$HOME/tools/jacocoagent0.7.4.jar=output=tcpserver,port=6300"
   ```
3. Run your application with embedded jetty server e.g. `mvn jetty:run`
4. Run your integration tests
5. In another shell, dump and report via `mvn jacoco:dump jacoco:report`
6. Open your report on `./target/site/index.html` (by default)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jacoco plugin to generate code coverage Here is the plugin configuration I used for junit test code coverage.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.10.201208310627</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    <output>file</output>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Note:** you may get life cycle not covered error in maven while using eclipse, one way is you explicitly mention the life cycle using plugin management. I installed the jacoco plugin from the market place which resolved my problem

Comment: I don't use Eclipse. I'm more interested in only producing the reports while running them on a CI server (Jenkins in my case) and storing the results to Sonar. Will this work...?

Comment: Not sure. I use eclipse/ command prompt. so in command prompt I run mvn test which will generate jacoco exec file after fork to jvm while running the test case. Then run mvn jacoco:report to generate report in html format

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar scenario where integration test were run on a jetty server. Also we needed a combined report for all the tests unit and integration. The solution we implemented was to run-forked jetty and pass the jvmargs with the jacoco javaagent details. Our code coverage reports covered all the rest api's and the service layer java code.
The pom config for jacoco

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-integration</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With the above config we generated a common exec file for both unit and integration test. Next we configured jetty to run-forked

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/myway</contextPath>
            <descriptor>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
        </webApp>
        <!-- passing the jacoco plugin as a jvmarg -->
        <jvmArgs>${failsafeArgLine}</jvmArgs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
                <waitForChild>false</waitForChild>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run-forked</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This would launch jetty in a separate jvm with the jvmargs. Finally we generated the report in the reporting tag of the pom. We noticed that adding the report to the build plugins did not capture the integration tests run by the jetty.

```
<reporting>
  </plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <reportSets>
            <reportSet>
                <id>jacoco-report</id>
                <reports>
                    <report>report</report>
                </reports>
            </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

The reports can be accessed at target/site/jacoco/index.html, alternately you can run it from the command line.

> mvn jacoco:report

Hope it helps.