# How to deploy EMMA coverage tool in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage, client-side, emma

I have a maven-based project with several lines on client-side. I have decided to get client-side code coverage using EMMA coverage tool. I deployed Jenkins v. 1.650 but there is no plugin related to EMMA. Available tab is empty and EMMA is not listed in the installed plugins. How should I get that?

Comment: emma plugin was replaced by jacoco

Comment: @aet but how can I get client-side code coverage with Jacoco?

Comment: That is a much bigger question, I dont know enough about your project to be helpful. maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128922/code-coverage-of-client-server-web-application

Comment: @aet thanks; I'll check it out.